# how to make a text as selectable?

Tags: android

I have some TextViews for phone no.
These are not editable. So I have made them as TextView.
I want to perform click action on phone no, i.e. on clicking phone no i have to make a call.
How to implement that? Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get that functionality is to set this parameter for your TextView in which you display the phone number:

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

Alternatively (not sure if this is a good practice though. perhaps someone could help out here), you can set it to

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

The later will detect any email addresses, website URL's, maps and convert them into relevant links on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

add ClickListener to that textview

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number = "tel:"+youPhoneNo;
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(callIntent, "Phone..."));
        }

    });
```

Comment: This solution is also good. But I think for my app which I use autolink property will be enough. Thanks for the support!!!